# Run CMD Command through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-prompt

I am trying to run a command in CMD, but would like to run in through PowerShell.

`Invoke-Item` opens CMD, but I don't how to pass in `program.exe argument > file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

To run cmd.exe from PowerShell, you don't need to use invoke-item e.g.:

```
cmd /c c:\windows\system32\ipconfig > file.txt
```

However, why not just run?

```
ipconfig > file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

try passing the command in directly with the full path qualifier of program.exe like:

```
$test= "c:\windows\system32\program.exe argument > file.txt"  
Invoke-Expression $test
```

Comment: - The argument contains an `.exe` file and some text...It's after the cmd.exe. So, it looks like this: `Invoke-Item c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe program.exe argument > file.txt`

Comment: try the alternative instead that I just edited. The cmd.exe is not needed.